# Java countdown of three seconds

Tags: java, android, countdown, stopwatch

I am working on a very simple card WAR game APP, and i wanted to display on a textview (3,2,1 -> WAR!).
I've tried this method:

```
public void doCounting(){
    for(int i=3;i>=0;i--)
    {
        if(i!=0){
        waitTv.setText("Wait "+i);
        SystemClock.sleep(1000);
        }else{
            waitTv.setText("WAR!");
        }

    }
}
```

It didnt worked it just make my app stuck for three seconds then enters the activity and place "WAR!" in the textView..

Comment: *it just make my app stuck for three seconds*. It is correct, because you are calling sleep on the UI Thread, which is also responsible to draw

Comment: Well, you *are* putting the main thread to sleep for three seconds, so that is what happens. Use an AsyncTask or Runnable/Handlers.

Comment: oh.. so how can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

The right way to do it is to use the `Thread.sleep(long milliseconds)`, although this method could throw an exception so you need to surround it in a try and catch like this.

```
try{
    Thread.sleep(3000);
}catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use this code:

```
CountDownTimer countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(3, 1000){

        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            waitTv.setText("Wait " + millisUntilFinished/1000);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            waitTv.setText("WAR!");
        }
    }.start();
```

Answer (score -1):

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

public class Stopwatch {
static int interval;
static Timer timer;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Input seconds => : ");
    String secs = sc.nextLine();
    int delay = 1000;
    int period = 1000;
    timer = new Timer();
    interval = Integer.parseInt(secs);
    System.out.println(secs);
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {

        public void run() {
            System.out.println(setInterval());

        }
    }, delay, period);
}

private static final int setInterval() {
    if (interval == 1)
        timer.cancel();
    return --interval;
}
}
```

Already on Stackoveflow [how to make a countdown timer in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14393423/how-to-make-a-countdown-timer-in-java)