# LocalDateTime in java countdown

Tags: java, immutability, countdown

I want to create a countdown class, which will countdown to a later, desired date(using only hours, seconds, and minutes, other stuff not important) from now. In a GUI I want to show the user the remaining time, updating every second with a Timer.

The problem is: if the user chooses a date late enough, for example: 23 hours 59 minutes 59 seconds till the countdown ends, that means I have to call `LocalDateTime.now()` more than 80000 times. 
 I read `LocalDateTime` is immutable, so I expect my `actualDate = LocalDateTime.now()` will leave a tons of unused objects back to the GC, which is sloppy. Is there a way around this with using only `LocalDateTime`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14393423/how-to-make-a-countdown-timer-in-java

Comment: What is the problem you have? And why do you not want to use a timer?

Comment: I want to use a timer, with at least a variable storing the remaining seconds till a programmed shutdown. But sooner or later it will be out of sync, so I must call something like `somedate = LocalDateTime.now()` frequently, which I do not think is a good idea, as I mentioned before, because `somedate` is immutable.There has to be a better solution.