# Spring Batch Scheduler : Timer implementation

Tags: java, spring

I have to build a online exam module which will be providing 10 minutes duration for exam completion.For implementing the timer part I was thinking to go with Spring batch scheduler.Refer to below config file:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task" xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task-4.3.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-4.3.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.3.xsd">

<context:component-scan base-package="mypackage" />

<bean id="timerService" class="mypackage.TimerService" />


<task:scheduler id="timerScheduler" pool-size="10" />

  <task:scheduled-tasks scheduler="timerScheduler">
     <task:scheduled ref="timerService" method="displayTimer"
         fixed-rate="1000" />
  </task:scheduled-tasks>
</beans>
```

During invocation I am invoking from a main method:

```
ClassPathXmlApplicationContext context = new 
ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring/applicationContext.xml");
```

Everything is fine except,timer will be strted as soon as the container is loaded.**But my aim is to start the scheduler as soon as user start the exam[eg:after a method invocation/button click] and not on application startup.**

Can anyone provide any clue in configuration for implementing such scenario.
**I know about `trigger` attribute but it generally works with cron expression and in my case trigger won't be based on time rather based on an event.
so,I cann't go via cron.**

Can anyone provide any suitable solution to this?
only how to invoke the scheduler based on a particualar method call rest I will implement by myself.

Comment: Use timer task instead of spring batch.

Comment: https://www.google.com/amp/s/howtodoinjava.com/spring-core/2-ways-to-execute-timer-tasks-in-spring-3/amp/

Comment: both are operating in same way.It is not the answer of my question.My focus is on the  invocation time.is there a way by which timer can be started after a button click or method invocation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such thing `Spring batch scheduler`, you are referring to Spring Framework's task scheduling.

Scheduling is incompatible with your requirement of "eg:after a method invocation/button click". Scheduling implies knowing the schedule upfront, but in your case, you don't know upfront when the user will click the button. What you actually need is to [start a count down timer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14393423/how-to-make-a-countdown-timer-in-java) upon a user action.