# Countdown Timer thread in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, timer, countdown

I want to make a countdown timer thread in Java. What I specifically want to do is run one part of a program, run and display the countdown timer for some time, and then resume the earlier program. I was trying to use Thread.sleep() for pausing the earlier program and running the timer for the exact same amount of time for which the program had been paused but I haven't been able to get the required output. Any method with which I could do it??
TIA!!

Comment: How have the [many existing Questions and Answers on countdown timers](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+java+countdown+timer&t=ipad&ia=web) not addressed your issue?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to make a countdown timer in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14393423/how-to-make-a-countdown-timer-in-java)